# OpenOffice / vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup, openoffice-calc

Why this function works on Excel but it does not work on OpenOffice:

`= vlookup ("*" & B2 & "*"; D5: E8; 1; false() )`

`=recherchev("*"&B2&"*";D5:E8;1;faux() )`

How can I do so that I can adjust it to work properly on OpenOffice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What `Calc` version used? Works for me using `LibreOffice Version: 6.4.6.2`.

Comment: Apache OpenOffice 4.1.9

Answer (score 0):

But I managed to do otherwise. Thank you anyway.

Basically I wanted to use this formula - which didn't work! - to return in each cell of a column an ​​entire paragraph that I have to find from a column which contains an extract in each cell of these paragraphs.

= vlookup ("*" & B2 & "*"; D5: E80; 1; false ())

I have in B2: B100 the extracts of the paragraphs.
I have in D5: E80 the entire paragraphs.

I wanted to find in D5: E80 if this snippet exists and return all the entire paragraph in another column.

That's why I used the star: "*" & B2 & "*".

If you have any leads for this kind of problem which may be useful for another time then that will be great.

Thank you again in advance.